# Changing qemu/libvirt default gateway IPv4 IP to something other than x.x.x.1/24

Tags: linux-networking, libvirt, qemu, virsh, virt-manager

**General info:**

---

I have a KVM-libvirt/qemu running on ArchLinux;

```
3.18.2-2-ARCH
ls | egrep -i 'libvirt|qemu'
libvirt-1.2.11-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
libvirt-glib-0.2.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
libvirt-python-1.2.11-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
qemu-2.2.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

**Problem:**

---

I'm running different firewalls (with multiple interfaces / Zones) and for DHCP issues while handling particular configurations I'd like to change the :

```
[root@localhost networks]# pwd
/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks
[root@localhost networks]# cat default.xml | grep address
  <mac address='52:54:00:66:9c:8c'/>
  <ip address='192.168.150.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
```

Which is the "gateway" for my networks and applied as an IP for the vrbrX interface to **something other than 192.168.150.1**, as for example if somehost behind the firewall takes the first available IP it will have the same IP so it will generate a network conflict (This happens as the firewall interfaces are bridges and hosts are found behind them.), and I don't want each time to change the networks to Static-IP's by turning off the DHCP (or other tweaks).

### **What I tried:**

Well, I tried editing manually the xml's of qemu/networks and than started the interfaces, but although the on the xml was :

Yet, the interface had

```
 25: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN        group default 
inet 192.168.150.1/24 brd 192.168.150.255 scope global virbr0
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't think the solution was so easy,

basically it should be edited with virsh net-edit which prompts you to vi, and than the change is applied also to the interface.

Strangely enough, I edited the xml, and it was applied also into the autostart directory and than started the interfaces,  so it seems like with virsh it does other operations as well.